# What is the difference between std::deque and boost::deque?

Tags: c++, boost

`std::deque` is rather well documented in [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), but `boost::deque`'s [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/container/deque.html) seems to be equivalent to that of the standard, with the addition of a few methods such as `nth` and `index_of`.

Are there other differences between the two classes that I am missing?

Comment: [ Boost.Container library implements several well-known containers, *including STL containers*. The aim of the library is to offers *advanced features not present in standard containers* or to offer the *latest standard* draft features for compilers that don't comply with the latest C++ standard.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/container.html#container.intro)

Comment: ... for example, boost deque can be used recursively; whereas using std::deque recursively is undefined; boost::deque offers full move semantics; including an emulation mode for c++03 compilers; but std::deque only supports move semantics in c++11 and higher. boost::deque supports polymorphic allocators, which are a proposal that may or may not be in C++17, etc.http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/container/history_and_reasons.html#container.history_and_reasons.Why_boost_container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are other differences. For example, `boost::deque` can be instantiated with incomplete types. So you can have this:

```
struct foo
{
  boost::deque<foo> foos;
};
```

whereas the following causes *undefined behaviour* (although it may work well on certain implementations.)

```
struct foo
{
  std::deque<foo> foos;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is UB? Unspecified Behavior would make more sense to me.